# Ember.js and UIKIT

Tags: ember.js, uikit, ember-cli

I try to add UIKIT to my Ember.js project

how to do it?

1: `bower install --save uikit`

All work fine on bower.json

i don't know what to put on ember-cli-build.js

e.g : app.import('bower_components/uikit/css/uikit.css');

How to do about js files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you import `js` files same way as `css` files,
if js files are in `bower_components/uikit/js/uikit.js` you do
`app.import('bower_components/uikit/js/uikit.js');`