# Get Ember.js and uikit together

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend, getuikit

I have a Problem with my Ember.js setup. I would love to use [uikit](http://getuikit.com) and installed it via `bower install --save uikit` and or over the Ember.js project dependencies. The *Problem* now is, that the JavaScript part won't work.

I also have googled and found this answer here on Stackexchange: [EmberJS and UIKIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465374/ember-js-and-uikit) but I have imported the uikit like ist is described already.

Thanks so far for helping me  
bMalum

Comment: Are you having issues with the css or the js part ? or both ? and could you tell us what kind of issue you're seeing ?

Comment: @Nazim CSS looks fine (but no round edges and so on) because the JS part is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `ember-cli-build.js`

after this:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defauts, {
});
```

you need to call import

```
app.import('bower_components/uikit/css/uikit.css');
app.import('bower_components/uikit/js/uikit.js');
```

once imported you should be able to use:

```
UIkit.button($(".button"), {/* options */});
```

or anything else in UIkit.
UIkit basically becomes a global object in the project.

Comment: Thank you! This helped. One very minor correction Your first line should be: `app.import('bower_components/uikit/css/uikit.css');`

Answer (score 1):

This probably wasn't an option for you at the time... now there is an addon/wrapper for it.

https://github.com/adfinis-sygroup/ember-uikit